# Created the same Program in Unix and Visual Studio 2010, the Visual Studio one wont compile

Tags: c++, unix, compiler-errors

We are using Emacs on Sun OS 5.9. I wrote the exact same code in both emacs and visual studio and put them in their own folders on the unix server. The one from emacs compiled without a problem but the one from visual studio wont. I opened the visual studio version in emacs and it looks just like the one i created in emacs but it wont compile. The compiler is g++
Here is the code:

```
// Samuel LaManna

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Hello World!";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    return 0:
}
```

And these are the errors i get when i try to compile the visual studio version:

> Intro.cpp: In function `int main()': Intro.cpp:14: error: expected`;'
>   before ':' token Intro.cpp:14: error: expected primary-expression
>   before ':' token Intro.cpp:14: error: expected `;' before ':' token
>   v245-2%

Comment: Evidently it wasn't the "exact same code".

Comment: Can you give the exact code that compiled in g++?  your posting does not work with g++: http://ideone.com/R5zP4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return 0:`

The error is right there.

`return 0;` with `;`

Comment: I'm glad I could help you Sam LaManna. Don't forget to accept this answer if it fixed your problem.

Comment: -1: that doesn't explain why it worked with g++.  For example, http://ideone.com/R5zP4

Comment: @Foo Doesn't seem like a legitimate reason to downvote. The answerer should not be held responsible for the errors of the asker. Nothing in the answer is _inexact_. In fact, it even solves the OP's problem. So why is it _bad_?

Comment: (I was the second person to down vote) the answer doesn't address the fundamental issue. The question was why this worked in GCC but not in visual studio. This post, while addressing a working solution, doesn't recognize that this should have been a problem with the GCC version as well (and the original issue is left unanswered). Hence the other person (and then I) down voted.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the colon in "return 0:" with a semi-colon "return 0;"

Answer (score 0):

You have `0:` as your return value; it should be `0;`.